# Why is WOW.js not working and leaving invisible elements behind?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wow.js

I have a website in my local pc and linked it to wow.min.js. (I dont know whether or not I should download the entire library or just that file; I did both ways but still no luck.) I tried:

With entire library downloaded:

```
<script src="WOW-master/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
```

With only this file in same dir:

```
<script src="WOW-master/dist/wow.min.js"></script>
```

And with this CDN:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wow/1.1.2/wow.min.js">
```

No luck with any of those ^
With all of those variations, I used this as the WOW Integration:

```
<script>new WOW().init();</script>
```

This would be the target element:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x wow slideInLeft" id="icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I know animate.css is working perfectly because if I write the above code like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x animate infinite slideInLeft" id="icons" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

I see the animation working, infinitely.

Instead of triggering when scrolled to, it just leaves the element with no visibility (visibility: hidden?) and you can't see the targeted element at all.

What could be the problem?

I downloaded all these files from the official gitHub page for WOW

A live link for the website is here:
http://stackoverflowproblems.site88.net/index.html

Bad site/host and no photos as they were too large (>1MB) for the free host I used. Also, the javascript is not working as soon as I uploaded it. but thats not the focus of this question. The code is still there so hopefully thats good enough. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a live link? or create a new **BIN** at [**JSBIN**](http://jsbin.com)

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Sure. Here: http://stackoverflowproblems.site88.net/index.html Its not the best site/host and most of the photos were too big to upload. But the code is there so.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Any Luck? By the way, whats supposed to animate in are the logos about "Lorem Ipsum"

Answer (score 1):

Iv'e had the same problem as you did, until i went back to my css and noticed i gave to the body tag a hidden overflow-x property :

```
body, html {
    /* Some stuff here */
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Once i removed it, this problem was resolved and the animations started working again, In fact, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/269) in the wowJS library. so in to resolve it, just remove the overflow-x hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add `overflow-x: hidden;` on your CSS or style. It won't work if you have `overflow-x: hidden;` on your styles.